# How can I map a private property in my base class?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Using fluent nhibernate, is it possible to map a private property in a base class?

I have this defined in my base class:

```
private DateTime? lastModifiedDT { get; set; }
```

but when I map it like so:

```
Version(Reveal.Property<EntityType>("lastModifiedDT")).ColumnName("LastModifiedDT");
```

I get a `FluentNHibernate.UnknownPropertyException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the property `protected` if you can.